# VSTO vb.NET - Get the name of existing worksheet controls

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, excel-addins

I'm developing an Excel Add-in using VSTO on vb.Net, where I'm struglling to get the names of the existing controls of a worksheet. In this project I'm adding two types of controls, a TableLayoutPanel and a NamedRange.
I loop the existing worksheet controls and I'm abble to get the type of the control, and in case of it be a NamedRange control I'm successfully getting its reference cell. Notwithstanding, I'm not able to get the name of both control types.

How can I get the name of the controls ?

The code bellow is where I'm creating the controls:

```
       `Dim painel = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
        Dim changesRange As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange

        Dim nomes As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names

        PanelsID += 1

        changesRange = ws.Controls.AddNamedRange(range, CStr("NamedRange_" & PanelsID))
        ws.Controls.AddControl(painel, range, "Panel" & PanelsID)

        Dim name1 As Excel.Name = CType(changesRange.Name, Excel.Name)
        'I could get the name of the control here
        MessageBox.Show(name1.Name)`
```

The code bellow is where I'm looping the existing worksheet controls:

```
   Function lerRange(ws As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet, range As Excel.Range) As Boolean
        Dim wsControls As Integer
        wsControls = ws.Controls.Count

        For i = 0 To wsControls - 1
            'Image1
            MsgBox(ws.Controls(i).GetType.ToString)
            If InStr(ws.Controls(i).GetType.ToString, "NamedRange") > 0 Then
                'Image2
                MsgBox(ws.Controls(i).RefersTo)
                'Image3
                MsgBox(ws.Controls(i).name.ToString)
            Else
                'Image4 - Using property name without toString()
                MsgBox(ws.Controls(i).name)
            End If
        Next

        lerRange = False
    End Function
```

[Output Image1 - Type of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7UMv.jpg)

[Output Image2 - Refering range of the NamedRange control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBFbg.jpg)

[Output Image3 - Output name of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcHnq.jpg)

[Output Image4 - Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOJpn.jpg)

Thanks in advance to the ones who could help !

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` property of `NamedRange` control has a capitel letter on the start **and** is an object. So you can try to get the name like this example.

```vb
...

For i = 0 To wsControls - 1
  If InStr(ws.Controls(i).GetType.ToString, "NamedRange") > 0 Then
    ...
    MsgBox(ws.Controls(i).Name.name)
    ...
  End If
Next

...
```

More informations do you get at microsofts docs for [NameRange.Name property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.name?view=vsto-2017).